# Expand/collapse odd row in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I want to expand/collapse a row, I want to hide all odd rows and on clicking '+' button those hidden row should get visible, my current code is allowing me hide all the odd rows but on clicking '+' button all row are getting visible, my use case is to show only the odd row which is next to clicked even row.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="test in ctrl.SearchResults">

        <tr ng-if="$even">
            <td>
                <button ng-click="ctrl.expanded = !ctrl.expanded" expand>
                    <span ng-bind="ctrl.expanded ? '-' : '+'"></span>
                </button></td>
            <td>{{test.apName}}</td>
            <td>{{test.type}}</td>

        </tr>
        <tr ng-show="ctrl.expanded" ng-if="$odd">
            <td></td>
            <td>{{test.apName}}</td>
            <td>{{test.type}}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason all the rows expand when you hit the plus, is that the variable `expanded` is on the controller. So all the rows are 'listening' to the same variable.

As atfornes pointed out in his answer, you could use the `$index` to identify each row. Another solution is to keep track of the current index on the controller and check for per row if he must be showed:

```
<tr ng-show="ctrl.expanded == $index" ng-if="$odd">
```

And on the click event of the plus sign you could have

```
ctrl.expanded = $index
```

Or you could handle this in the controller. In this case you can create a method on the controller which accepts the index and then set this index value to the controller's variable `expanded`.

Answer (score 1):

At the button ng-click code, you could store the current $index with a code like:

```
<button ng-click="ctrl.expanded = !ctrl.expanded; ctrl.index = $index" expand>
```

then, you can change the ng-show condition to only display the item if ctrl.expanded and $index === ctrl.index + 1:

```
<tr ng-show="ctrl.expanded && $index === ctrl.index +1" ng-if="$odd">
```